# Find the inverted value of the string

Tags: php, strings, palindrome

How can this be optimized?

```
$text = "reverseesrever"; // Reverse and esrever
$b = false;

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
    if($text[$i] !== $text[strlen($text) - 1 - $i]) {
        $b = true;
        break;
    }
}

echo ($b) ? "YES" : "NO"; // result: NO.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title of the question is confusing. The code seem to check if the text is not the same if you read it backward. For example, it `$b` will be true for "hello" and false for "level". In other words, you're checking if some text is NOT a palindrome. I think you should change the title to better reflect what the code is doing.

Things to improve:

- It's enough to iterate until `strlen($text) / 2`, no need to go all the way until the end
- To avoid re-calculating the length of the string, it's better to calculate it once before the loop and reuse it
- Wrap the whole thing in a function to make it easier to reuse and to test
- The `!==` is unnecessary, a simple `!=` would do

For example:

```
function isPalindrome($text) {
    $length = strlen($text);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length / 2; $i++) {
        if ($text[$i] != $text[$length - 1 - $i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function test_isPalindrome($text) {
    printf("isPalindrome(%s) -> %s\n", $text, isPalindrome($text) ? 'YES' : 'NO');
}

test_isPalindrome("reverseesrever");
test_isPalindrome("hello");
test_isPalindrome("aba");
test_isPalindrome("aa");
test_isPalindrome("ab");
```

Outputs:

```
isPalindrome(reverseesrever) -> YES
isPalindrome(hello) -> NO
isPalindrome(aba) -> YES
isPalindrome(aa) -> YES
isPalindrome(ab) -> NO
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using `strlen` method each cycle 2 times, that means that if you have a string which is long 100 characters, then you will use `strlen` 200 times!

   For cycle in PHP works like this:

   ```
   for (expr1, expr2, expr3){

   }
   ```

   - `expr1` is evaluated once
   - `expr2` is evaluated in the beginning of each iteration
   - `expr3` is executed at the end of each iteration

   You should calculate the length of string before using it in for cycle.

   Read more about for cycle in [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).
2. As mentioned in the other answer by @janos, you don't need to iterate over whole string, but you still need to know the length of whole string for this condition:

   ```
   if($text[$i] !== $text[strlen($text) - 1 - $i]) {
       $b = true;
       break;
   }
   ```

   Otherwise you will always get `YES` as result.
3. You can use `''` for wrapping your string instead of `""`. In the second case PHP interpreter does not need to check for variables inside the string. This does not have any noticable impact on performance.
4. You are using `!==` but in this case it is sufficient to use `!=`, however, this does have any noticable impact on performance as well.
5. If you are going to reuse the code, you might consider wrapping it into a function.

   I rewrote your code (no function included):

   ```
   $text = 'reverseesrever';
   $iterateLength = strlen($text) / 2;
   $length = strlen($text) - 1;

   $b = false;
   for($i = 0; $i < $iterateLength; $i++) {    
       if($text[$i] != $text[$length - $i]) {
           $b = true;
           break;
       }
   }

   echo ($b) ? 'YES' : 'NO';
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm missing the point of your function, but I feel it could be a lot shorter and more efficient.

I suggest using a simple `strrev()` to reverse the string, for comparison.

Try,

```
$string = 'reverseesrever';
echo ($string === strrev($string)) ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

I've used the same strings as a previous answer, and I get the same response.

```
"reverseesrever" -> YES
"hello" -> NO
"aba" -> YES
"aa" -> YES
"ab" -> NO
```

This would cut out iterations and multiple calls to `strlen`.